# Faulty memory maniplation w / linked lists

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

The last printf call (printf("%d\n", current->val);) will not be executed. After the 1st printf functions' results appear, I am given the error "program.exe has stopped working". I would appreciate some help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int val;
    struct node * next;
} node_t;

void print_list(node_t * head);

void main()
{
    node_t * head = NULL;
    head = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    if (head == NULL)
        return 1;
    head->val = 3;
    head->next = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    head->next->val = 2;
    head->next->next = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    head->next->next->val = 3;
    head->next->next->next = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    head->next->next->next->val = 18;

    print_list(head);

    head->next->next->next->next = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    head->next->next->next->next->val = 5556;
    head->next->next->next->next->next = NULL;
    node_t * current = head;
    while (current->next != NULL) 
    {
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    current->next->val = 32;
    current->next->next = NULL;
    printf("%d", current->next->val);
    system("pause");
}

void print_list(node_t * head) {
    node_t * current = head;

    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", current->val);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure print_list would work ? Since the time print_list is called, the last node does not point to null. So, the printing logic would probably fail.

Comment: Use functions for node insertions and deletions. Doing so is the sought after way managing linked list.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, guys! Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

This won't go well:

```
head->next->next->next = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
head->next->next->next->val = 18;

print_list(head);
```

You never initialized `head->next->next->next->next` to NULL.  Instead, use `calloc`, or explicitly set the value to NULL.  Even better, write a function to create a new node so you never forget to initialize.  Even better still, write a function to insert a node.

What about something like this:

```
node_t * create_node( int val ) {
    node_t *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    if( node ) {
        node->val = val;
        node->next = NULL;
    }
    return node;
}

node_t * insert_value( node_t *list, int value ) {
    node_t *new_node = create_node( value );
    if( !new_node ) {
        return list;
    } else if( list ) {
        new_node->next = list->next;
        list->next = new_node;
    }
    return new_node;
}
```

Then you can:

```
node_t *head = insert_value( NULL, 3 );
node_t *tail = head;
tail = insert_value( tail, 2 );
tail = insert_value( tail, 3 );
tail = insert_value( tail, 18 );
print_list( head );
```

A common approach for lists is to use a *dummy head* node, which you never print out.  It only contains a `next` pointer which is the start of your list and you ignore the value.  If you did this, then you could also use that `insert_value` function to insert a value before the first element of the list.  You also get the benefit that `head` *always* manages your entire list and you never have to worry about it changing.

Comment: Thank you! Even though it was that simple, it would've taken me too much time to figure it out, if ever!